# Непонятные ошибки в Java

Tags: java

Написал две функции, вот первая:

```
static void funcX (int xx)
{
    x = xx;

    while (xx < 5)
    {
        System.out.print ("|");
    }
}
```

И вот вторая:

```
static void funcY (int yy)
{
    y = yy;

    int result = funcX() * yy;

    System.out.println (result);

}
```

При запуске обеих функций по очереди, возникает непонятная (для меня) ошибка:

> /MyClass.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
>           x = xx;
>
> symbol:   variable x
>     location: class MyClass
>   /MyClass.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
>          y = yy;
>
> symbol:   variable y
>    location: class MyClass
>   /MyClass.java:51: error: method funcX in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
>           int result = funcX() * yy;

Comment: где объявлены переменные `x` и `y`? `int result = funcX() * yy;` - `funcX` ничего не возвращает. Что Вы умножаете на `yy`?

Comment: @Igor такой же вопрос

Comment: static int x = chisla.nextInt(); static int y = chisla.nextInt();

Comment: @НеНужноЭто Где находится эта строчка кода?

Comment: @Igor В функции main

Comment: @НеНужноЭто Эти переменные не видны внутри функций `funcX` и `funcY`, перенесите их декларацию в тело класса.

Comment: @НеНужноЭто добавь полный код в вопрос

Comment: Вы вызываете funcX() без аргумента, в то время как он прописан.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что вы умножаете на возвращаемое значение метода `funcX()`, который ничего не возвращает. Советую использовать хорошую IDE, которая подсказала бы эту ошибку.

Comment: Intellij IDEA Community на пример.